# Git mega squash all sequential commits with same message and author

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

I have an [application](https://github.com/grenade/teamcity-config-monitor) which monitors a file-system (TeamCity config directory), for changes to XML configuration files. When a change is detected, it is committed to Git (with [libgit2sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp)). The Git 'Committer' is always the service account user that the application runs under, but the Git 'Author' is determined by examining the TeamCity audit log so that the change is attributed to the user who made it. The application records a generic commit message like "build configuration 'x' was modified by user 'y'." and commits the change.

Since TeamCity configuration changes tend to be made as a series of web page interactions, we end up with lots (10 to 30 or so) of sequential commits, showing the change to a given configuration file (generally, the same one (build-config) or two (vcs-config) files are changed in the whole series of commits).

I want to squash all sequential commits with the same commit message and author into a single commit. Is there a git command that can do this for a whole repo in one shot or do I need to script a sequence of calls for each sequence of commits that I want to squash?

When working with libgit2sharp, I have found that it makes sense to work out what I want to achieve in vanilla git and afterwards implement the git command in the c# code. but perhaps someone already knows the correct sequence of libgit2sharp calls to make this work.

Comment: If you can list all the `(start,end)` commits, e.g. via your own custom script employing `git for-each-ref` there is an automated way to squash all of those, but it involves `git replace` and can seriously break the history *across* branches. I'm a bit reluctant to post it as an answer, I'm not a big fan of such rewrites, but let me know if it is something that is of interest to you.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's ever been used to compress history before, but you could experiment with LibGit2Sharp's [RewriteHistory](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/393b3bcdc91e2c8652344b3eab3db188afcbbaa9/LibGit2Sharp/ReferenceCollection.cs#L349-L370) api. Check out [the tests](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/393b3bcdc91e2c8652344b3eab3db188afcbbaa9/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/FilterBranchFixture.cs) for how it's usually invoked. Some combination of `TreeFilter` and `ParentFilter` might do what you want.